# Having one color code either in hexadecimal or RGB. Keeping this as base, need to generate lighter & darker gradient colors based on percentage in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a base color code (in this example it is "#0078D4") either in hexadecimal or RGB. Keeping this as base, I need to generate lighter and darker gradient colors based on %percentage. Is there any C# code or algorithm there to achieve this?

`#004478  |   Darken 18%    | rgb(0,68,120)`

`#005ba1  |   Darken 10%    | rgb(0,91,161)`

`#006fc5  |   Darken 3%     | rgb(0,111,197)`

`#0078D4  |   rgb(0,120,212) |`

`#0086ed  |   Lighten 5%    | rgb(0,134,237)`

`#4fb3ff  |   Lighten 24%   | rgb(79,179,255)`

`#bae1ff  |   Lighten 46%   | rgb(186,225,255)`

`# d9efff |   Lighten 51%   | rgb(217,239,255)`

`# edf7ff |   Lighten 55%   | rgb(237,247,255)`

Comment: As a whole lightening something, you add the same r/g/b to each, so, if you took that in and max it at 255, min it at 0 etc.. it should all work out.  as for the hex, Im sure you can convert hex to a number

Comment: You should convert to HSV or HSL, then change the brightness and then convert back.

Answer (score 1):

in `System.Drawing` you can use:

```
Color color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
var h = color.GetHue();
var s = color.GetSaturation();
var l = color.GetBrightness(); <-- increase or decrease
```

in `System.Windows.Forms` you can use the

`ControlPaint.Light/Dark Method

```
var result = ColorPaint.Dark(rgb(0,68,120), .18);
```